# Difference between state data and destructuring in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is very basic of React but I really need to understand why it is behaving in this way. 
Is there any difference between this part of code :
Example1:

```
increment = () => {
const { count } = this.state; // doing destructure ...
this.setState({ count: count + 1 }, () => {
console.log("Clicked times: ", count);
});
};
```

and this part Example2:

```
increment = () => {
//const { count } = this.state;
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }, () => { //putting "this.state.count" directly
console.log("Clicked times: ", this.state.count);
});
};
```

Because when I do the second way (Example2), then I get the correct output:
Its asynchronous way and show the same data both in browser and in console. Why the first example does not work in correct way, is it because I am saving the value in a new variable ( by doing de-structuring).
Here is my Whole code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/counting-in-react-j0uyc

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should really be setting the state as a function. `this.setState(count => count++)` This way you will always get a mutable state copy and don't have to mutate the current state (i.e. `this.state.count + 1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. The reason `decroment` does not look like it is working is because you are making a copy of `this.state.count`

For example. If `this.state.count` was 1. At the top of the `decrement` function, you are making a local variable `count` with the value 1. You are then updating `this.state.count` to 2, however, the local `count` is a full copy (not a reference) so will not be affected by this update.

You can see they are the same if you replace `console.log("Clicked times: ", count);` with `console.log("Clicked times: ", this.state.count);`

Answer (score 1):

In the distructure example you set the state as `count+1` then console the `count`. but when you update the `state` it's update the `state`, not the local variable `count`, so you console the old count.

If after `this.setState({count: count+1})` you console the `this.state.count` anything will look fine

Comment: Missing `{}` around the `setState` parameter.